# I am not finding the add custom command option in the extensibility tab of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sdk, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have installed VS SDK for VS2013. But I am not finding any option to add custom command inside C# Extensibility. Am I missing something? Note that I have done same thing in VS 2017 and VS 2019 and it is working for me. Screenshot of VS2013 can be found here -[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Q6a.png).

Comment: Which project type is this?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not finding the add custom command option in the extensibility
>   tab of Visual Studio 2013

As far as I know, the Custom Command Item Template is a new feature of vsix project since VS2015. You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-menus-and-commands?view=vs-2015).

This is VS2015 document:

[image]

**So** if you use VS2013, you can not get what you want. **And VS2013 does not support extending menus and commands for VS IDE.**

**And** if you want to extend them, you should target to use **VS2015+**.

**Update 1**

**First**, thanks to **Ed Dore** for the guidance. VS2013 does not have such Custom Command Item Template and if you still want to get it in VS2013, you should add that command in **.CS**, **.VSCT** file manually and then add necessary code to realize it. Actually, it can be done in VS2013 to create a custom command.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: This is not correct. YOu can certainly add custom menu commands to earlier versions of the Visual Studio IDE. It's just that you have to manually edit the .VSCT and .CS files to add the necessary code. While it's true there is no Custom Command item template to do this for you, adding commands to VS 2013 is most certainly supported. You just need to do the coding by hand.